# Deploy python worker to heroku without running immediatly

Tags: python, heroku, scheduled-tasks, worker

I have a simply python script that I deploy on Heroku as worker:

Procfile:

```
worker: python main.py
```

The script is scheduled to run every day at a specific time with the `Heroku Scheduler`. I don't want it to run to other times.

Every time I push new changes to heroku (`git push heroku master`) the script is run automatically which I want to avoid.

How can I do that?

I looked into using another scheduler, that is set up from within the script like the [APScheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python). Would this be a solution? Do I need to change my script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [scale the `worker` dyno formation down](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#manual-scaling) to zero:

> If you want to stop running a particular process type entirely, simply scale it to `0`

So:

```
heroku ps:scale worker=0
```

Jobs scheduled via Heroku Scheduler should still run as configured.